# Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP in OpenShift w/ custom domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, openshift

I've a Bronze account with a custom domain. I've a `secure` subdomain configured to use an SSL cert, which is working fine. However, I want to force HTTP (ie.e., no SSL) on the root domain. However when I browse to `https://example.com` I am getting the shared SSL certificate that belongs to `example-myuser.rhcloud.com`.

**How can I disable HTTPS for for all subdomains except `secure`?**

My aliases are set up as:

```
Alias                 Has Certificate? Certificate Added
--------------------- ---------------- -----------------
example.com        no               -
secure.example.com yes              2014-07-26
www.example.com    no
```

As you can see I have one domain (secure) configured to use an SSL cert.

My attempt at this was with the following htaccess rules, but they don't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# disable https on the root
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write htaccess for subdomain redirection to https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840669/how-to-write-htaccess-for-subdomain-redirection-to-https)

Comment: As you can see my htaccess rules are already setup like that question's answer suggests. I think there's something specific to the configuration w/ openshift. As you'll note my secure subdomain /already/ works as desired despite the utter lack of htaccess rules for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close, but `SERVER_PORT` is the wrong way to go on OpenShift ([see here](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-)).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# disable https on the root
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: This trick didn't work for me for some reason. What I did is just added URL redirect record on DNS from "www" to URL without www and it solved my problem.